# In LC-3 assembly language, how do I store a value at a specific place in memory (presumably with offsets)?

Tags: assembly

If the program counter is sitting at location x3050 and I want to store register R5's value in location x3075, what command do I use?
I think I need to use offsets but I'm not sure of what command to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
ST R5, x19
```

The OFFSET is computed by taking the difference between the location you want to store the value in and the PC. (see source to verify)

x3075 - x3050 = x19

http://www.scribd.com/doc/4596293/LC3-Instruction-Details